# How to print tabs in PHP in Debian - works in windows

Tags: php, tabs

I have a simple PHP script I'm running from the command line using php -f:

```
<?php

echo "\t" . 'test';

?>
```

On windows it prints the tab in the output, but Debian appears to be ignoring the tab. Is there something else I need to do on Debian to print the tab? Maybe some other escaping?

Thank you!

Comment: Works fine on my debian server.

Comment: May I ask what version of Debian & PHP you have? We have Debian 7.9 and PHP 5.5.12.

Comment: Debian 8.3 and PHP 7.0.4

Comment: But also works fine on PHP 5.6.17. I don't think this is an issue of Debian or PHP, but the used software to run the cli commands.

Comment: try adding this line to the top of your PHP script and see if it changes anything: `header('Content-Type: text/plain');`